# How to push failed promises to separate array?

Tags: javascript

I am looping through ids that sends it to an async function and I want to return both success and failed data, right now I am only returning success data

```
    const successContractSignature: LpContractSla[] = [];

for (const id of lpContractSlaIds) {
  const data = await createLpSignature(context, id);
  if (data) {
    successContractSignature.push(data);
  }
}

return successContractSignature;
```

If the createLpSignature throws error, do i need a try catch here? but wouldnt that exit the loop?
How can I push failed data to separate array without breaking the loop?

Comment: "do i need a try catch here? but wouldnt that exit the loop?" — Why would it exit the loop? Unless, I suppose, the `try/catch` was around the loop instead of inside it … so don't do that.

Comment: Take a look at `Promise.catch()` which will allow you to handle a throw.  Your example should really show what you want to do with success/failure conditions in regards adding them to the result array - i.e. how will they be differentiated.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's a specific reason to avoid the call in parallel, it's always a good practice to avoid to start async calls in a for loop with await, since you are going to wait for each promise to resolve (or reject ) before executing the next one.
This is a better pattern which lets you also get all the results of the promises, either they resolved or rejected:

```
const successContractSignature: LpContractSla[] = await Promise.allSettled(lpContractSlaIds.map((id: string) => createLpSignature(context,id)))

return successContractSignature;
```

But if for some particular reason you need to make these calls in a sequence and not in parallel, you can wrap the single call in a try catch block ,that won't exit the loop:

```
for (const id of lpContractSlaIds) {
let data;
try {
  data = await createLpSignature(context, id);
} catch(e) {
  data = e
}
  if (data) {
    successContractSignature.push(data);
  }
}
```

You can test it in this example:

```js
const service = (id) =>
  new Promise((res, rej) =>
    setTimeout(
      () => (id %2 === 0 ? res("ID: "+id) : rej('Error ID : '+id)),
      1000
    )
  );

const ids = [1,2,3,4,5]

const testParallelService = async () => {
  try {
  const data = await Promise.allSettled(ids.map(id => service(id)))
  return data.map(o => `${o.status}: ${o.reason ?? o.value}`)
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}  
testParallelService().then(data => console.log("Parallel data: ", data))


const testSequentialService = async () => {
  const res = [];
  for (const id of ids) {
    let data;
    try {
      data = await service(id);
    } catch (e) {
      data = e;
    }
    if (data) {
      res.push(data);
    }
  }
  return res;
};

testSequentialService().then((data) => console.log('Sequential Data: ', data));
```

Comment: try/catch isn't the only way here.  `res.push(await service(id).catch(e => e))`

Comment: I don't think I said it's the only way, I used the words "you can" :) .